# Border radius on hidden div 'smears' in IE10 when using jQuery toggle function

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

This works fine in all browsers except IE10.

When using a simple jQuery toggle function on a hidden div it results in the bottom corners leaving this jagged 'smear'. I've never seen this before. I guess it's something to do with the border-radius css but I don't have any problems with this in Firefox or Chrome. Any ideas what's going on here? Is this an IE 10 bug or am I doing something dumb?

[image: IE10 bug]

Here is a link to the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JwZLs/16/)

HTML:

```
<div id="app_cont">

    <div id="game_pnl">

            <div id="hid_div"></div>

            <div id="btn_cont" unselectable="on">
                    <a href="#" id="def_btn" class="app_btns"  unselectable="on">Submit</a>

            </div>

    </div><!--#game_pnl-->

</div><!--#app_cont -->
```

CSS:

```
    #app_cont {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    height: auto;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 100px auto 100px auto;
    background: #efefef;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    padding: 10px;
}


#btn_cont {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #dcdcdc;
    clear: both;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.app_btns {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    min-width: 90px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: normal;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #ababab;
    padding: 9px 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(5%, #ededed),
        color-stop(100%, #dfdfdf) );
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100%);
    filter: progid :   DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient (  
             startColorstr =   '#ededed', endColorstr =   '#dfdfdf' );
    background-color: #ededed;
    color: #777777;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.app_btns:hover {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(5%, #dfdfdf),
        color-stop(100%, #ededed) );
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #dfdfdf 5%, #ededed 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #dfdfdf 5%, #ededed 100%);
    filter: progid :   DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient (  
             startColorstr =   '#dfdfdf', endColorstr =   '#ededed' );
    background-color: #dfdfdf;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.app_btns:active {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}

#hid_div {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    background: #f1e8ba;
    width: 482px;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    float: left;
    display: none;
    padding: 8px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #313131;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#def_btn').on('click', function(){

    $('#hid_div').slideToggle(250);

});
```

Comment: No _CSS_, no _HTML_, no _JS_... It's very hard (_if not impossible_) to help you here: can you provide some codes?

Comment: Yes you are right. I don't know why I didn't include code in the first place. I have updated it now to include code and JSFiddle. Thanks.

Comment: Working fine on firefox 21, probably an IE problem.

Comment: Yes. It works fine in all other browsers, it's just in IE where there is the issue.

Comment: Just IE10 as per your title yes? Just double-checking as it works fine in IE9...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matt,

From what I've tested on your JSFiddle code, this is a bug in Internet Explorer 10. What appears to be happening is that IE10 does as your JavaScript code says and slides the element out. However, it does so in a way that it does not initiate a redraw of the *parent* of the *parent* element at each frame of the animation, which causes the current frame to be drawn on top of the previous frame, thus giving it the jagged look. Basically, it doesn't erase the previous frame of the element with id `app_cont` and it draws over it after changing the css properties of the child element `hid_div` to make it appear to be sliding out. I would imagine that this would be discovered by Microsoft soon and fixed in some sort of update for IE10.

However, in case it isn't fixed any time soon, the best workaround to fix this (in my opinion) would be to *not* use Jquery for sliding out the element and instead make your own "raw" JavaScript function to increment the height property over a certain period of time. Below are links to two Youtube videos that do what I suggested, and after trying the code in IE10, it seemed to be working fine -- meaning no jagged edges. I would suggest watching both so you get a thorough understanding of this concept.

I tried to post the code from the two Youtube tutorials on JSFiddle, but for some reason it didn't work (but I tested it out for real with IE10 and it worked fine). The source code for the tutorials is available in the descriptions for the videos.

One thing that you will have to do different, however, is to change the height of *two* elements at the same time; the first being the div with id `hid_div` and the second element being the parent div with id `app_cont`. If you can understand those tutorials thoroughly, though, it shouldn't be challenging at all. The reason you have to change the height of the `app_cont` div is because that will force a redraw each frame for that element, thereby eliminating the jagged edges.

[Fade Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1tGtL6upTEU)

[Slide Out Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=byBk8z_FqTs)

Thank you for asking your question, tcs08

Comment: Thank you, I had forgotten about this but I will definitely take a look at those tutorials. Thank you.